# Is webAudio no longer supported on iOS 15/16, is it a Bluetooth glitch, or is there some workaround required to get basic webAudio to play?

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, web-audio-api

As far as I can tell, the most basic webAudio functionality no longer works on iOS mobile Safari, or else some weird new requirement is now in place.  Code that runs fine in other browsers (including desktop Safari) produces no errors, but no sound in mobile Safari.
I have tried many ultra-simple examples of a user gesture to play a basic sound.
I just discovered that these examples WILL produce audio on iOS Safari, but only if bluetooth is not being used and has not been used.  Once bluetooth audio is used, as far as I can tell the only way to get webAudio to work again is to restart the Safari browser (with bluetooth off).
Here's one live example on the web:
https://codepen.io/LegDip/pen/KKQOMRr
Here's the code:

let context;
    let mediaStream;

```
function createAudioContext() {
    if (context == undefined) {
        context = new AudioContext();
    }
    return context;
}

function playTone() {
    const audioContext = createAudioContext();
    // play a tone
    const oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
    oscillator.frequency.value = 440;
    // don't play at max volume
    const gain = audioContext.createGain();
    gain.gain.value = 0.04;
    oscillator.connect(gain);
    gain.connect(audioContext.destination);
    oscillator.start();
    // stop after 10 seconds
    oscillator.stop(audioContext.currentTime + 10);
}
```

Here's another completely independent example, which once again works fine in other browser contexts.  The function playTone is called directly by a user button tap in a vue app:

const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)({ sampleRate: 44100 });
playTone() {
audioContext.resume()
const oscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
oscillator.frequency.value = 440; // A4 note (440 Hz)
oscillator.connect(audioContext.destination);

oscillator.start();
oscillator.stop(audioContext.currentTime + 1); // Stop after 1 second
}

I've tried a number of other ultra-simple examples and everything under the sun that either me or chatGPT can think of to fix it.

Is there a fix?

Is it possible to wrap a webapp in chromium to solve this, or on iOS will that have the same problem?

Does the world just need to all simultaneously toss their iPhones in the sea?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure it's not a specific problem with your device? I can run all that  on my iPhone, on myiPad

Comment: Thanks.  Were you able to run it with Bluetooth?  I can't figure out what's going on.  I have repeated the problem on multiple devices and simulator.

Comment: I'm able to run it with or without Bluetooth, on internal speaker and trough my AirPods. iOS 16.5.1

Comment: Can you run [this](https://pro-audio-live-assistant.vercel.app/signal_generator.html)? I'm an audio engineer, it's a very little utility I use in my live shows

Answer (score 2):

I'm reasonably sure that there is a bug in WebKit where it doesn't handle audio hardware sample rate changes correctly (which is very likely to be the case if you use Bluetooth).

For example, if you open a web page that uses WebAudio on an iOS device with Bluetooth not connected, the AudioContext will have a sampleRate of 48000. With the page open, if you connect to an external Bluetooth speaker (which has a sampleRate of 41000) and return to the page, the audio is distorted because the AudioContext is using the wrong sampleRate (i.e. 48000 instead of 41000).

I've filed a bug report regarding this (which includes a demo page to test against): https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=258864

Note that WebKit is used for all browsers on iOS and iPadOS, so if your problem is related to mine (and I suspect it is), using another browser won't help.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help with this.  I can select any sampling rate that I want.  Is there a sample-rate that can be used that will solve this problem so audio 'works' on iOS?  Also -- and maybe this is related -- I'm finding all kinds of audio glitching when doing time-stretching of audio, but only on iOS.  I've tried many approaches to work around this.  HTML 'playbackRate', and webAudio using time shifting, many algorithms.  All work great on all other platforms.  Have not found a way to make even reasonable-sounding time-shifted audio for a webapp on iOS. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I followed the instructions on your demo page, and: 1) on my iPad the audio plays just fine, without pitch change or other unintended modifications. 2) scrolling the page, audio becomes "crackly".  This maybe a buffer issue

Comment: 3) No artifacts while playing through audio element

Comment: 4) Sometimes when I tap stop, the music stops with audible "cracks". Not 100% reproducible for me

Comment: @user2330237 - glad to help ! Unfortunately, although the specification suggests that you can set the sample rate of a new AudioContext, it doesn't seem to make any difference on iOS.
Personally, I've come to the conclusion that the Bluetooth issue that I've reported cannot be detected nor avoided using JavaScript in the web page.
So, for the player that I'm working on, we're telling users to make sure they don't change the output device while the page is loaded.
That is: set the output device first, then open the player web page.

Comment: @pierpy - it seems that you do not have the Bluetooth issue that I've experienced. May I ask what setup you have (i.e. iPhone model, iOS version, make and model of external Bluetooth speaker) ?
My guess is that the problem may depend on the Bluetooth hardware and / or codec that's being used.

Comment: Regarding the audio glitches, I suspect it could be because WebAudio is on a lower priority thread than the one that handles user interactions.
In my player, we use the WebAssembly version of a library called Superpowered https://superpowered.com which does all the "heavy lifting".
Unfortunately, even it can't work around bugs in WebKit / WebAudio !

Comment: Finally, in WebKit, the HTML <audio> element is considered a "first class citizen" and is treated the same way as audio produced in a native app.
Unfortunately, WebAudio is not treated in the same way and suffers as a result
So, for example on iOS, audio played using the <audio> element continues to play if you switch to another app.
That's not true for audio played using WebAudio.

Comment: @peegee123 yes: iPhone13, model number MLPF3QL/A ,  iOS 16.5.1 AirPods 2nd gen; my bluetooth speaker is a low-end  chinese model, no brand. iPad 6° gen, MRJN2TY/A, iPadOS 16.5.1

Comment: @pierpy - thanks for the info. Based on what you have, it should show the problem. Would you mind trying my demo page on your iPhone again but before openng the page make sure that Bluetooth is enabled, your Bluetooth speaker is ON but ALL devices are showing as "Not Connected" in the settings including your AirPods.
Then, when following the instructions, make sure you do not refresh the page at all and only play audio through either the internal speaker or the Bluetooth speaker.